# Call API until desired answer is given

Tags: ios, uitableview

I will try to explain my issue as best as I can.

So the idea is to refresh tableview datas. I've set a pull to refresh to do so.

When the pull to refresh is trigger I need to do a basic API call which will set a value to 1. Setting si value to one will make the server performing actions. To know when the server is done I have to repeatedly call it (with an other very light API call I can trigger as many time as I want) and check if the value set to one is back to 0.

So I need a block call setValue and inside of it I need an other block call getValue. I need to "run" the second block (getValue) as many time as needed until I get the right answer and then stop the second block calls and finally update my tableView.

I have already tried lots of things... I don't want to use an NSTimer.
I starting to lose my mind here...

By advance thank you :)

Comment: If you need to poll the server then NSTimer would be the way to do it. Why don't you want to use NSTimer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Note: **Calling an API repeatedly is not a best approach**, It will cause battery drain easily.

But to get you a solution , you can go by following steps.

First set a `BOOL` flag in your declaration.

```
BOOL isResponceCameForFirstPart;
```

Then You can call the first function from your `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
      isResponceCameForFirstPart = NO;
     [self callAPItogetFirstStep];
     [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
     }
```

Now, You need to call the API in recursive way until you get the response you desire.

```
- (void)callAPItogetFirstStep{
    // Call the API here and get the response here.
    if(desireAnswer){
        isResponceCameForFirstPart = YES;
        [self  callAPItogetSecondStep];
  }else{
         [self callAPItogetFirstStep];
    }  
  }
```

Finally you can call the second step after getting desired response.

```
- (void)callAPItogetSecondStep{
}
```

Comment: We can do it with or without  out using performselector by calling the method  directly. If it will block main thread, we can use GCD too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I used your approach worked perfectly !
My mind gone too far thinking about dispatch / Nsoperation / semaphore... 
I have read a lot of literature on the other hand... Still nice :)